# Is profit margin the same as net profit margin?

Tags: reference-request, finance

I'm quite confused by these two terms because different websites define them differently.

Answer (score 1):

Profit margin is profit after the cost of sales. If you review an income statement, you will see revenue, and then typically a data field called “cost of selling goods”. Revenue - Cost of sales is profit margin.

Net profit margin is Revenue - all expenses. So this includes taxes, interest expense, administrative expenses, and ALL expenses. An easy way to remember this is that profit margin is simply revenue - the cost of selling products, and net profit margin is revenue - ALL costs.